# Collapsing duplicates in R where only the unique column values get concatenated

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I need to collapse a large table (5M by V19) where I remove duplicates based on a specific column (V1), combine the values of all other columns if unique (if not, then report the result only once).

I've tried some solutions from here but those examples were mostly performed on 2 variables - I have 19. What ends up happening is that entire rest of the table gets combined in a single numeric list column.

Input:

```
V1         V2         V3         V4         V5         V6
TR1000     chr1       1000       1200       A          + 
TR1000     chr1       1000       1200       B          + 
TR1000     chr1       1000       1200       C          +  
TR2000     chr2       2000       2500       D          +   
TR2000     chr2       2000       2500       E          + 
TR3000     chr3       3000       3500       F          +
```

I need:

```
V1         V2         V3         V4         V5         V6
TR1000     chr1       1000       1200       A, B, C    + 
TR2000     chr2       2000       2500       D, E       +  
TR3000     chr3       3000       3500       F          +
```

Comment: `aggregate(.~V1,df,unique)` or rather `aggregate(.~V1,df,function(x)toString(unique(x)))`. If you are getting numbers instead of values its just because you have factors so reread your data in with the option `stringAsFactors=FALSE` or do `df = rapply(df,as.character,'factor',how='replace')` or use the `groupby +summarize` from `dplyr`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, [edit] your question and show what you have tried so far. In particular, show the code which causes the " entire rest of the table gets combined in a single numeric list column". Thank you.

Comment: Please, clarify what your problem is in going from 2 to 19 variables. The sample dataset has only one column `V5` which needs to be collapsed. All other columns have unique values for each `V1`. This probably will stimulate answers which just aggregate/collapse `V5`.

Comment: I have made up a table representative of the one I actually work with. Putting in the actual table wouldn't be optimal as it is rather large and contains complex terms. That said, @www gave me a suggestion that works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using the `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by_at(vars(-V5)) %>%
  summarize(V5 = toString(V5)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(names(dat))
dat2
# # A tibble: 3 x 6
#   V1     V2       V3    V4 V5      V6   
#   <chr>  <chr> <int> <int> <chr>   <chr>
# 1 TR1000 chr1   1000  1200 A, B, C +    
# 2 TR2000 chr2   2000  2500 D, E    +    
# 3 TR3000 chr3   3000  3500 F       +
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "V1         V2         V3         V4         V5         V6
TR1000     chr1       1000       1200       A          + 
TR1000     chr1       1000       1200       B          + 
TR1000     chr1       1000       1200       C          +  
TR2000     chr2       2000       2500       D          +   
TR2000     chr2       2000       2500       E          + 
TR3000     chr3       3000       3500       F          +  ",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
byCols <- setdiff(names(dat), "V5")
dat[, .(v5 = toString(V5)),  by = byCols]

       V1   V2   V3   V4 V6      v5
1: TR1000 chr1 1000 1200  + A, B, C
2: TR2000 chr2 2000 2500  +    D, E
3: TR3000 chr3 3000 3500  +       F
```